# Integrating Assetic with Phing and custom framework

Tags: php, phing, assetic

Our product is developed by using an in house framework. We are using PHP (5.4) together with Twig as a tempting system and Phing for deployment.

Lately, we were facing a problem to update our Javascript and CSS minifier\compressor because of code legacy and we decided to look for other solutions.

We found Assetic library that manages all of the related assets (css,js) and its tools (compiler,caching, S3 etc) and we were thinking how to integrate into it. While doing that, we had to consider the following:

- Assetic supports the ability to let frontend developers to define their css\js needs by using Twig, which means that they won’t have to touch the server side code.
- Today we are defining our assets through the server side because of our deployment script that needs to minify\compress it and then create a new “compiled\gzip” script\css - we want to have the ability to skip this part and not to have the need to define server side for assets.
- It is also important to us to keep the current integration with our CDN. While deploying we upload our assets\static data to the CDN.
- We want to be able to support 2 modes:

  - “Source Mode” - meaning that while developing we would be able to use the scripts with  minifier\compiler\merge and use them as if they are being loaded one by one
  - “Merged Mode” - merged and compiled\minified (by configuration) and ready for deployment (should be support on development for QA)

By mentioning the above, we would like to have some ideas of how to integrate Assetic with our application **without** changing our core framework and to apply what was considered before and written above.

Thanks